# Ektron smart form configuration for if else logic in c#

Tags: c#, ektron

Can i configure the below condtion in ektron smart form. Please advise

```
if (((Context.Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("nexus") || 
      Context.Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("android")) && 
      !Context.Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("mobile")) || 
       Context.Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("ipad"))
    DeviceType = "Tablet";
else if (Context.Request.UserAgent.Contains("Mobi"))
    DeviceType = "Mobile";
else
    DeviceType = "PC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can use a Choices Field in your Smartform, set to be of type radio button.  Add a radio button for Nexus, Android, Mobile, Ipad, etc.  The "text" property for each will be "Nexus", "Android", etc while the "value" property can be "Tablet", "Mobile", etc.

Using the examples you have given, you could set your choices like so:

- Nexus - "Tablet"
- Android - "Tablet"
- Mobile - "Tablet"
- iPad - "Tablet"
- Mobi = "Mobile"
- Other = "PC"

Your content authors can then choose from one of those values when using the Smartform.

Comment: Can you say me how to retrieve the key and value in c#.And also the logic here with some and or logic shall we keep that as well in the key value pair.

Comment: I mean the logic in the key value pair.((Context.Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("nexus") || 
      Context.Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("android")) && 
      !Context.Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("mobile")) || 
       Context.Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("ipad")